# Python won't import parent package within a subpackage

Tags: python, importerror

Here is the file structure of my current project:

```
mechanism
│   .gitignore
│   dataframe.py
│   mechanism.py
│   vectors.py
│   __init__.py
│
├───examples
│       temp.py
│       __init__.py
```

I would like to be able to use the contents of the parent package in any file under `examples`. In `temp.py`, I have the following line:

```
from ..vectors import Vector
```

This raises the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gmbra\Downloads\Python Programs\Mechanisms\mechanism\examples\temp.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ..vectors import Vector
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

I'm not sure what is going on here because I have following the syntax according to section 5.7 found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports) in the docs. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Try running `from ..mechanism.vectors import Vector`

Comment: You can do `sys.path.append(os.realpath(os.dirname(__FILE__)+'/..'))` before your import.

Comment: Are you executing `temp.py` directly?

Comment: Yes I am executing temp.py directly. More specifically, I will be executing .ipynb files under the examples directory. @SethMMorton

Comment: @M.Chak It needs to be a relative import because the `mechanism` name can change when someone does `git clone <repo path> .` into whatever they decided to name the directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment you mentioned that you are executing `temp.py` directly. When you do this, the `temp.py` package namespace is not considered to be a sub-package of `mechanism` but instead it’s own package. This is the reason it does not work.

If you intend to be calling the files from `examples` directly, it is best to move them out of the package and do `from mechanism.vectors import Vector`.

Actually, you might be able to keep it a sub-package and just change the import to the above suggestion.

Comment: You are correct. It will run when I do that, but the problem is that the parent directory of `examples` (`mechanism`) is subject to change. But my end goal is to make a package out of this, so when someone runs `pip install mechanism`, the name will always be `mechanism`. The absolute import may work then.

Answer (score 0):

`temp.py` is top script in your project structure, not in a python package. While `relative import` is the concept of package scope. So you get the error.

Typically, for your scenario, the suggest solution is as next:

**temp.py:**

```
from vectors import Vector
```

**execute:**

```
$ cd mechanism
$ PYTHONPATH=. python3 examples/temp.py
```